# Add mask on UICollectionViewCell when center position

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection view with custom cells. And I don't undestand how I can change my UILabel in collection view from black to red color when cell is centered in the view.

[image]

Comment: Please be more detailed and show what you have tried already (code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Cell #\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if let tableView = scrollView as? UITableView {
            for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
                adjustCellColor(cell: cell)
            }
        }
    }

    func adjustCellColor(cell: UITableViewCell) {
        let cellFrame = tableView.convert(cell.frame, to: view)
        if cellFrame.contains(view.center) {
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` (and `UITableViewDelegate` protocol inherits from `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol) so when your view controller is a delegate for the `UITableView` you can implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods like `func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)`. This method is called when table view is scrolled. It iterates through all visible cells and sets text color to red if the cell is in the center of the view or black otherwise.